# Xpath how to get text from descendant nodes

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I have something like this:

```
<div id="m0">
...
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>Radio</td>
 </tr>
</div>

<div id="m1">
...
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td> 
    <a>TV channel</a>
    <font color="#555555">...</font>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
     <i> </i>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td> 
     <i> Other channel </i>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I want to get this as result: `['Radio','TV Channel',' ','Other channel]`

I have tried to do: `ch_nodes=tree.xpath('//div[@id="%s"]/table[@class= "fl"]/tr/td[3]/descendant-or-self::*'%div)`

After that for each node i get the text but it gives me nodes that i do not want like `<font>`content.

I have tried this too :`ch_nodes=tree.xpath('//div[@id="%s"]/table[@class= "fl"]/tr/td[3]/descendant-or-self::*[2]'%div)` but does not give me the self content if does not have child nodes.

How can i get `['Radio','TV Channel',' ','Other channel]` ?

Comment: State the criteria that distinguishes the text that you do want from the text that you do not want.

Comment: I want the first text in that tag even if it is empty. Can be in the child tags or in the td tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get each first text-node from `tr`:

`$x("//table//tr//*[1]/text()")`

If you want to get each first non-empty text-node from `tr`:

`$x("//table//tr//*[boolean(string-length(normalize-space(text())))][1]/text()")`